# Prestashop 1.7.2 Total amount include tax

Tags: open-source, prestashop-1.7

I have prestashop 1.7 application. In that application i need to show total amount include tax. Now its showing total amount excl tax. I ll attach the image for reference. Anyone please tell me if possible to show total amount.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the backoffice you can enable this really easy. Go to 'International > Taxes' if you scroll down there is the option "Display tax in shopping cart".